# Htmlunit, bad encoding when submit post

Tags: htmlunit

Good day!
Do send a message to the forum.
When sending my data break
[image]
[image]
added to the header charset, it did not help
What could be the problem?

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
page = webClient.getPage(urlPage);
HtmlForm formEditPost = page.getFormByName("postform");

HtmlTextInput subjectInput = formEditPost.getInputByName("subject");
subjectInput.setText("заголовок");

HtmlTextArea messageElement = formEditPost.getTextAreaByName("message");
messageElement.setText("сообщение");

HtmlSubmitInput sendMessage = formEditPost.getInputByName("post");
page = sendMessage.click();
```

Comment: Regardless of what you see there, do the posts contain question marks?

Comment: there is should be a text instead of questions, if the text was in English it's displayed